# emulate group_concat in MSSQL, ambiguous column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

I am currently trying to simulate the `group_concat` function in MySQL to MSSQL. I have followed code formats found in [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aXrRmMBS-g1kJ%3ablog.shlomoid.com/2008/11/emulating-mysqls-groupconcat-function.html%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ph) and [here](http://anthony-yio.blogspot.com/2007/12/mssql-groupconcat.html). The problem is, when I try to execute the query, I get the message `Ambiguous column name` for my column `RoleID`. Here is my query:

```
select UserName, RoleID from tb_UserInRoles
cross apply(
    select RoleName from tb_Roles
    where tb_UserInRoles.RoleID = tb_Roles.RoleID
    for XML Path('')
) fxMerge (RoleID) group by UserName, RoleID
```

I'd like to know why this particular code format present the `Ambiguous column name` error message. I need to make this query work and understand it. Thanks in advance for the help.

I plan on using this in a many-to-many relationship table, wherein users of a system can have multiple roles, like this:

```
|  User  |   Role  |
|--------|---------|
| JamesP |  Maker  |
| JamesP | Approver|
| JamesP |  Admin  |
```

I want the result query to be like this:

```
|  User  |           Role           |
|--------|--------------------------|
| JamesP |  Maker, Approver, Admin  |
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT UIR.UserName, MAX(STUFF(fxMerge.RoleID, 1, 1, '')) 
FROM tb_UserInRoles UIR
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT ',' + RoleName 
    FROM tb_UserInRoles UIR1 
    INNER JOIN tb_Roles RM ON UIR1.RoleID = RM.RoleID
    WHERE UIR.UserName = UIR1.UserName 
    FOR XML PATH('')
) fxMerge (RoleID) 
GROUP BY UIR.UserName
```

Comment: @JamesP Check my updated answer. It will resolve your problem. I had joined on the `USERNAME` column because I don't know the table structure. So you have to join on `USERID` column if you have. Change in query is WHERE `UIR.UserId = UIR1.UserId` instead of `UIR.UserName = UIR1.UserName`

Comment: it works brilliantly now :) If you don't mind, I'd like to know which does what in the code, like, why did you use MAX and STUFF, why use INNER JOIN etc.

Comment: @JamesP Subquery returns all the role name for particular user so I had to join both tables. the subquery returns `,Maker,Approver,Admin` for JampesP user. So I need ro remove first comman. So I have use STUFF function to implement this

Comment: @JamesP Inner query not subquery.